# Xamarin iOS free provisioning build issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Using the [free provisioning](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/) guide, I am trying to deploy my `Xamarin.iOS` app to my `iphone` from `VS2015` on windows.

I have successfully created my provisioning profile and signing certificate in XCode 8 on mac. To test in Xcode, I have deployed the blank application to my iphone and it got installed.

In Visual Studio 2015 on windows PC, for my `Xamarin.iOS` project, I have correctly set my signing identity and provisioning profile in the iOS Bundle signing and build sections to match exactly the Bundle Identifier set in Xcode. When I try to deploy in visual studio by selecting my iphone, I get the following error message:

The root assembly

```
/Users/sierra/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/ec18ea611871f94799e79be973662048/bin/Debug/MyTunesiOS.exe conflicts with another assembly (/Users/sierra/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/ec18ea611871f94799e79be973662048/bin/Debug/MyTunesiOS.exe).
```

Is there any other setting that I need to configure or change that is required to deploy from Visual Studio 2015 on windows with free provisioning.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have two or more instance of an app in your phone?

Comment: Just one instance. According to the error message, both assembly are pointing to the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to conflicting versions of xamarin.ios in windows and mac. Updated them to same version and it worked.